# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. when i lunch Fragment or Activity and inside both of them i m using firebase

Tags: android, firebase

i tried to many way like **"Asynctask, Threads,Ui Threads"** but always have this problem check my code and log when i lunch this given activity

Here is One Acitvity Code

```
public class MoreDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    private MembersModle member;

    private String selected_Category = "Members", childKey;
    private int No;

    AlertDailogbox alertDailog;
    ProgressDialog progressBar;

    private static final int CALL_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int STORAFGE_REQUEST_CODE = 4;

    private TextView tv_Name, tv_Phone, tv_Email, tv_Web, tv_address, tv_company, tv_Category, tv_Job;
    Button btn_Edit, btn_share, btn_del, Make_Call, Do_Chat;
    CircleImageView img_Profile;

    String storagePermission[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_more_detail);
        createRefrences();

        Intent i = getIntent();
        selected_Category = i.getExtras().getString("Category");//will get Category of the Card
        childKey = i.getStringExtra("Key");//get possition of the item
        No = i.getIntExtra("no",0);

        member = new MembersModle();

        //storagepermission
        storagePermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

        showProgressBar();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        myRef.child(selected_Category).child(childKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                getDataFromFirebase(dataSnapshot);
                                setDataIntoField();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                }
                });
            }
        }).start();



        Make_Call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                makePhoneCall();
            }
        });

        Do_Chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                smsIntent.putExtra("address", tv_Phone.getText().toString());
                startActivity(smsIntent);
            }
        });

        btn_Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent m = new Intent(MoreDetailActivity.this, ManualCardActivity.class);
                m.putExtra("activity", "MD");
                m.putExtra("category", selected_Category);
                m.putExtra("key", childKey);
                startActivity(m);
                finish();
            }
        });

        btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!checkStoragePermissions()) {
                    requestPermissionStorage();
                } else {
                    showShareDailoge();
                }
            }
        });

        btn_del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setTitle("Deleting Data");
                progressBar.setMessage("Please Wait While Data is Deleting From the Server");
                showDeleteDailoge();

            }//onclick
        });

        tv_Web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(!tv_Web.getText().toString().trim().equals("No Web Address")){
                   final String HTTPS = "https://";
                   final String HTTP = "http://";
                   String URL = tv_Web.getText().toString().trim();

                   if (!URL.startsWith(HTTP) && !URL.startsWith(HTTPS)) {
                       URL = HTTP + URL;
                   }

                   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));
                   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose browser"));
               }else {
                   Toast.makeText(MoreDetailActivity.this, "Sorry No Web Address Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

            }
        });

    }

    private void makePhoneCall() {
        String number = tv_Phone.getText().toString();
        if (number.trim().length() > 0) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MoreDetailActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MoreDetailActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, CALL_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                String dial = "tel:" + number;
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial)));
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MoreDetailActivity.this, "Something Happend Worng Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    private void getDataFromFirebase(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        member.setName(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class));
        member.setAddress(dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class));
        member.setCompany(dataSnapshot.child("company").getValue(String.class));
        member.setEmail(dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class));
        member.setJobTitle(dataSnapshot.child("jobTitle").getValue(String.class));
        member.setOfficePhone(dataSnapshot.child("officePhone").getValue(String.class));
        member.setWebsite(dataSnapshot.child("website").getValue(String.class));
        member.setImageUrl(dataSnapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class));

    }

    private void setDataIntoField() {
        tv_Category.setText(selected_Category);
        tv_Name.setText(member.getName());
        tv_company.setText(member.getCompany());
        tv_Email.setText(member.getEmail());
        tv_Phone.setText(member.getOfficePhone());
        tv_Web.setText(member.getWebsite());
        tv_address.setText(member.getAddress());
        tv_Job.setText(member.getJobTitle());


        if (!member.getImageUrl().equals("No")) {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(member.getImageUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.userprofile)
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(img_Profile);
        }
        progressBar.dismiss();
    }


    private void showProgressBar() {
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressBar.setTitle("Getting Data...");
        progressBar.setMessage("Please Wait While fetching from the Server. Thank You");
        progressBar.setCancelable(false);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.show();
    }

    private void showMsgDailog(String Title, String Msg, Boolean CloseActivity) {
        alertDailog = new AlertDailogbox(Title,
                Msg, CloseActivity);
        alertDailog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "alert Dailog");
    }

    private void createRefrences() {
        img_Profile = findViewById(R.id.image);
        tv_Name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        tv_company = findViewById(R.id.company);
        tv_Email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        tv_address = findViewById(R.id.address);
        tv_Web = findViewById(R.id.webAddress);
        tv_Phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        tv_Category = findViewById(R.id.category);
        tv_Job = findViewById(R.id.job);

        btn_Edit = findViewById(R.id.edit);
        btn_share = findViewById(R.id.share);
        btn_del = findViewById(R.id.del);

        Make_Call = findViewById(R.id.call);
        Do_Chat = findViewById(R.id.chat);
    }

    private void showDeleteDailoge() {

        progressBar.setTitle("Deleting Data");
        progressBar.setMessage("Please Wait While Data Is Being Deleting From the Server");

        final AlertDialog.Builder dailog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MoreDetailActivity.this);
        dailog.setTitle("Delete Card");
        dailog.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want To Delete Card");
        dailog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                showProgressBar();

                MoreDetailActivity.RunableThread run = new RunableThread();
                new Thread(run).start();



                int random = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.dismiss();
                        if(No == 1){
                            Intent i = new Intent(MoreDetailActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }else {
                            Intent i = new Intent(MoreDetailActivity.this, ShowSelectedCardsData.class);
                            i.putExtra("category",selected_Category);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }, random);

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        dailog.setCancelable(false);
        dailog.create().show();
    }

    private void removeChildFromDataBase() {
        if (!member.getImageUrl().equals("No")) {

            mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(member.getImageUrl());

            mStorageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                    myRef.child(selected_Category).child(childKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MoreDetailActivity.this, e.getMessage() + "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            myRef.child(selected_Category).child(childKey).getRef().removeValue();
        }

    }

    private void showShareDailoge() {

        final ShareCardAs shareCardAs = new ShareCardAs(MoreDetailActivity.this);

        AlertDialog.Builder dailog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MoreDetailActivity.this);
        String[] options = {"As Text", "As Image"};
        dailog.setTitle("Share Card");
        dailog.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {

                    shareCardAs.shareAsText(member, selected_Category);
                }
                if (which == 1) {
                    RelativeLayout mycard = findViewById(R.id.mycard);//this is the view which we pass to the ShareIamge Class


                    shareCardAs.getscreenshot(mycard);//generate Image And Save in
                    shareCardAs.shareImage();
                }

            }
        });
        dailog.create().show();
    }

    private boolean checkStoragePermissions() {
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);


        return result;
    }

    private void requestPermissionStorage() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, storagePermission, STORAFGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == CALL_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                makePhoneCall();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == STORAFGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            if (storageAccepted) {
                showShareDailoge();
            } else {
                showMsgDailog("Access Denied", "Please Allow Application To Storage Permission First", false);
            }
        }
    }

    //new thread
    private class RunableThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            removeChildFromDataBase();

        }
    }

}
```

i m new in development please **Help**
**Here Is The run Log when i lunch this activity**

when i lounch this Activity

```
{I/{WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@3683c3e[MoreDetailActivity], this=android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@9f5c26b, pkg=com.webfabricant.schedular
D/ViewRootImpl[MoreDetailActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=ShowSelectedCardsData, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-4448375020125780822, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MoreDetailActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4448375020125780821}]
W/InputTransport: ARC dlopen LIB: libARC.so fail with dlopen failed: library "libARC.so" not found
I/InputTransport: Create ARC handle: 0x7d3b0b15c0
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@63a47b5, this = DecorView@3683c3e[MoreDetailActivity]
I/Choreographer: Skipped 11 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7d3b11a000,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7d3b11a000)
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 234906334
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7d3b0ab000)
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7d3b0ab000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
I/Choreographer: Skipped 5 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7d3b11a000,api=1)
D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@abbbda7[Getting Data]
I/InputTransport: Destroy ARC handle: 0x7d3b0b1620
I/Choreographer: Skipped 4 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7d442d0000,api=1)
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent =android.view.ViewRootImpl@aa61062, this = DecorView@a2fd8f1[ShowSelectedCardsData]
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service}
```

Comment: did you filter  the log based on your application? This error look like some other application not yours.

Comment: runOnUiThread inside the thread make cause. use  Asynctask it can update result to UI.

Comment: Starting a Thread from the UI thread to only call runOnUiThread makes no sense, you should clean this up

Comment: you are right #Ryan M

Comment: i m very tiered by trying to remove this error.i also try to comment the code inside onCreateView But still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd suggest you to read more about Android threads and specially the UI thread and why it is used for: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

What `I/Choreographer: Skipped 11 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` is telling you is that you are executing too much stuff in the main (UI) thread, keeping that thread busy and incapable of rendering 11 frames.

You should identify which part of your code is causing the issue in order to take actions, and at a first glance this looks like a good candidate:

```
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        myRef.child(selected_Category).child(childKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                getDataFromFirebase(dataSnapshot);
                                setDataIntoField();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                }
```

You should try to only run in the main thread the code that is actually interacting with the UI and see if it helps.

Comment: i check it now by comment this all code which is download data from firebase and set in to the field but still on the lucnch of activity i get this error help me if you can